# MongoDB Query to find the list of customers who has SELL and PURCHASE Both

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I am using mongoDB as NoSql Database. I have two collections One is **CUSTOMER**(**CID**,CNAME) and Other one is **SHOP**(Bill_No, Type, Amount,**CID**)

In SHOP Collection, **CID** is referenced with Customer(CID).Also Type can be either "SELL" or "PURCHASE".

```
db.CUSTOMER.insertOne({"CID":1,"CNAME":"Mark"});
db.CUSTOMER.insertOne({"CID":2,"CNAME":"Chris"});
db.CUSTOMER.insertOne({"CID":3,"CNAME":"James"});
```

```
db.SHOP.insertOne({"Bill_No":1,"TYPE":"SELL","Amount":1000,"CID":1});
db.SHOP.insertOne({"Bill_No":2,"TYPE":"SELL","Amount":350,"CID":2});
db.SHOP.insertOne({"Bill_No":3,"TYPE":"PURCHASE","Amount":450,"CID":1});
db.SHOP.insertOne({"Bill_No":4,"TYPE":"PURCHASE","Amount":360,"CID":3});
db.SHOP.insertOne({"Bill_No":5,"TYPE":"SELL","Amount":800,"CID":3});
```

What should be query to find the list of customers who has SELL and PURCHASE Both.
So according to given data the output should be like

"CID":1, "NAME":"MARK"
"CID":3, "NAME":"JAMES"

Thanks in advance..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Demo - https://mongoplayground.net/p/ZXylHb2g7Dm

- Get all details linked to `CUSTOMER` from `SHOP` using [$
  lookup](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup/)
- Use [$group](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/) combine all types into 1 document
- To match both types `"PURCHASE", "SELL"` use [$all](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/all/)

---

```
db.CUSTOMER.aggregate([
  {
    $lookup: {
      from: "SHOP",
      let: { c_id: "$CID" },
      pipeline: [
        { $match: { $expr: {$eq: [ "$CID", "$$c_id" ] } } },
        { $group: { _id: null, types: { "$addToSet": "$TYPE" } } },
        { $match: { types: { $all: [ "PURCHASE", "SELL" ] } } }
      ],
      as: "trades"
    }
  },
  { $match: { "trades.types.0": { $exists: true } } },
  { $project: { _id: 0, CID: 1, CNAME: 1 } }
])
```

Comment: What if we have to show only the number of Entry of each customer. For Ex :- Mark has 2 accounts , Chris has 1 account and James has 2 Accounts.  I have written this query but it is showing the whole record but i have to show only the Number of Entries of each customer.   Please Check Here :-  https://mongoplayground.net/p/8NLC4NLMYYZ

Answer (score 0):

You can use `$lookup` for `aggregation`, click [here](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup/#-lookup--aggregation-) for reference.

**Syntax**

```
{
   $lookup:
     {
       from: <collection to join>,
       localField: <field from the input documents>,
       foreignField: <field from the documents of the "from" collection>,
       as: <output array field>
     }
}
```

In your case the query would be

```
db.CUSTOMER.aggregate([
   {
     $lookup:
       {
         from: "SHOP",
         localField: "CID",
         foreignField: "CID",
         as: "SELL_PURCHASE"
       }
  }
])
```